# Launch R process from Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to launch a process when doing some interation on Shiny, but not using source, because I want that it runs on new R process, so if someone close Shiny windows, it still being working. How can I do it?

Here is my app:

```
library(shiny)

ui<- fluidPage(
inputbutton("button","Launch R process")
)

server <- function(input,output){
output$text <- renderText(
#Here is where I think that R process must be executed
print("The process has been launched")
)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: You mean launching a R script in another session ?

Comment: Yes, thats what I want

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html) if you want to get started with parallel computing in `shiny`.

Comment: Thanks , but this is not what I need... Maybe with cron jobs?